# Defining rotation along curve with array/curve modifier

Tags: modeling

I want to make a floating road follow a path. To do so I have a small rectangular prism that is the width of the road, which I apply an array followed by a curve modifier. At the moment it looks like the image below:

[image]

For the composition, I need the road to be relatively flat along the curve, however I can seem to find a way to locally change the rotation of the road to follow a logical bank. Rotating the object just rotates the entire thing. I have tried the empty object offset method from other questions however it doesn't let the road follow the curve at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the curve and in the *Object Data panel > Shape > Twist Method*, choose *Z-Up*:

[image]